# Reflexivity and Polymorphism

Tags: java, web-services, inheritance, reflection, polymorphism

I have to write a method wich can use webservices dynamically simply by passing the webservice full qualified class name as a String argument.
I have a getPort method in my webservice class.
I have written a small code snippet to get all the signatures of the method. Here is the output:

```
Méthode 1
javax.xml.namespace.QName
java.lang.Class


Méthode 2
javax.xml.ws.EndpointReference
java.lang.Class
[Ljavax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;


Méthode 3
java.lang.Class
[Ljavax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;


Méthode 4
java.lang.Class


Méthode 5
javax.xml.namespace.QName
java.lang.Class
[Ljavax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;
```

I assumed that the '[L' before class name was for 'abstract'.
So i wrote this method:

```
public static Class<?>[] getTypes(Object[] args){
    Class<?>[] paramTypes = null;
    if(args != null)
    {
        paramTypes = new Class[args.length];
        for(int i=0;i<args.length;++i)
        {
            if(args[i] instanceof javax.xml.ws.soap.MTOMFeature){
                paramTypes[i] = args[i].getClass().getSuperclass();
            }
            else{
                paramTypes[i] = args[i].getClass();
            }
        }
    }
    return paramTypes;
}
```

But i have the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.****.****.****.****.****.****.getPort(java.lang.Class, javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1670)
at test.testws.createServiceSoapPort(testws.java:160)
at test.testws.main(testws.java:44)
```

If i delete the 'instance of' test i got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.****.****.****.****.****.****.getPort(java.lang.Class, javax.xml.ws.soap.MTOMFeature)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1670)
at test.testws.createServiceSoapPort(testws.java:160)
at test.testws.main(testws.java:44)
```

---

EDIT

How can i modify

```
if(args[i] instanceof javax.xml.ws.soap.MTOMFeature){
    paramTypes[i] =   args[i].getClass().getSuperclass();
}
```

To have something like that:

```
 if(args[i] instanceof javax.xml.ws.soap.MTOMFeature[]){
    paramTypes[i] =   ArrayOf(args[i].getClass().getSuperclass());
}
```

I could write:

```
paramTypes[i] =   Class.forName("[L"+args[i].getClass().getSuperclass().getName()+";");
```

But i really think it sucks.

---

I need some help to understand that in order to solve this problem.
Thanks

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect: "[" indicates an array, followed by the element type name.

Comment: 'L' means the element type is an Object (not primitive). it is followed by the name of the class. you should have `javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature` class in the classpath

Comment: Yes i have it in classpath